Email Template doesn't save changes of twig view
Hello everyone I have problem with my email template when I change something in my twig view and send email again I have always the first state of view I don't no why the change has not saved.
I use
php bin/console cache:clear

but same thing the email still the first state of twig view without recent changes

I think is Symfony bug because the TemplatedEmail class rendering one time a view and always use the first time of rendering view. And the solution is to use 'html' function and use controller rendering view 'renderView' to generate a view with actual update like bellow
$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
        ->from(new Address('support@yourdomain.com', 'Support Team'))
        ->to((string) $user->getEmail())
        ->subject('Password reset request')
        ->html($this->renderView('reset_password/email.html.twig', ['resetToken' => $resetToken,
            'name' => $user->getLastName()]))

    ;

After that all done 

Affaik there is no black magic integrated within Symfony. The class doesn't save his first render. There is probably some wrong usage, and you should provide more context files on how you use those template.
